# How to add new items to existing menu using custom module

Tags: routes

Is there any way to add new items to an existing menu using custom module in Drupal7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Drupal 6 you do use menu_link_save:

```
$item = array(
  'link_title' => 'Menu title',
  'link_path' => 'menu/path',
  'menu_name' => 'menu_name',
  'module' => 'your_module',
);
menu_link_save($item);
```